# Wrong generic less then function

Tags: c, generics, void-pointers

I assumed that the following function can get any datatype such as float, double, long, and long long and return a correct answer. Unfortunately, it does not. Can anyone explain why? My aim is to create a generic "less than" and implement something similar to

```
int le_generic(const void* a, const void* b){
return *(long long*) < void *(long long*)b;
}
```

PS:

I have tried the suggested below:

```
void *aptr1, =const &m->data[m->heap[i]];
void *b = &m->data[m->heap[j]];
double c = m->data[m->heap[i]];
double d = m->data[m->heap[j]];
printf("%d, %d\n", le_generic(*a,* *b)ptr2, csize_t <num d);
```

but with

```
#define le_generic(a,b) ((a)<(b))
```

Comment: Just because all those types do not use the same machine representation?

Comment: If you need some kind of generic in C, you may use a macro `#define le_generic(a,b) ((a)<(b))`

Comment: I am sorry. Can you explain the mechanism of the suggestion above? If I use < on void type it does not work, right?

Comment: How is casting to `long long*` going to work when the data size is less than 8 bytes? Why do you need a function instead of just using `<` ?

Comment: I do not. I assumed that the significant bits are in the beginning anyway and therefore it will work anyway. I do not argue as I do not have the right background. I am truly trying to learn here. I use < on void type it does not work, right? why your suggestion will?

Comment: Suppose you want to compare two 1-byte values which are the same. The following 7 bytes may not be the same, so the comparison of two 8-byte values will give the wrong result. Also if the inputs are `unsigned` then your cast to `signed` may give the wrong result.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks for your answer. Shouldn't it know the length of the memory for the same reason you have mentioned? maybe that is the reason it did not work for me (please see my edit)

Comment: "Shouldn't it know the length of the memory" No, in C *you* should know the length of the memory.

Comment: Do you want to compare pointers or values? Calling `le_generic` with pointers (to void or not) is non-sensical. That macro just compares two values (expected of the same type to work properly).

Comment: Even if it does know the size of the value, your cast overrides it. But it won't: a `void*` pointer definition contains no size information.

Comment: `*(long long*)a < *(long long*)b;` is **undefined behaviour** unless both `a` and `b` actually point to a `long long` or `unsigned long long` or their cv-qualified counterparts.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, I tried to printf("%d, %d\n", le_generic(*a, *b), c < d); but it does not compile

Comment: You can't compare voids! Void is a type with no value!

Comment: I figured out that I had formulated my question with the emphasis on the suggested answer, rather than the search for the solution. Your suggestion is correct but it is not what I was looking for. I rephrased my question.

Comment: You can't change the question like this! This is forbidden! This is another question. I tried to answer the original one.

Comment: What means: *distinguishing between < and =,> rather than <, =, and >*???

Comment: You are right. I will open another question

Comment: Sorry, seems I can not do it.

Comment: What is this gibberish from the last edit: `returnmemcmp *(long long*)aconst <void *(long long*)b;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can not work because different data types uses different machine representations.

Defining `int le_generic(const void* a, const void* b)` lets you call that function with pointers to any data type. This violates the standard constraints on comparing elements of the same type alas with your definition:

```
int a;
double b;
le_generic(&a,&b);
```

is an acceptable call.

Worst is `*(long long*)a < *(long long*)b` which assumes that what you pass is necessarily pointers to `long long`, which is never the case except in one case:

```
long long a, b;
le_generic(&a,&b);
```

There is no genericity in C. You can not define a generic function.
My workaround would be to define a macro, which is roughly a syntactic replacement. When you define:

```
#define le_generic(a,b) ((a)<(b))
```

that means that everywhere you use `le_generic(sometext,othertext)` the compiler will replace it with the exact expression `((sometext)<(othertext))`.
You can then use it like this:

```
int i1, i2;
le_generic(i1,i2);
float f1, f2;
le_generic(f1,f2);
```

etc. Alas there is then no type checking; that is the problem with macros.

Of course you can not use `void` too. Looks like you are mistakenly confusing `void` and `void *`. `void` is a type with no value. You can not declare a variable of `void` type, nor try to manipulate `void` value (there is no). `void *` is a type of all possible addresses, it is a type that has values! That type is wrongly sometimes called the generic pointer type (should be better called the supertype of all pointer types), that may be the source of your confusion. There is no genericity (in your meaning) there. When you try to dereference a `void *` you get a `void` then no value!

Comment: see my edit to clarify

Comment: corrected. Will open a new question